# ImportError: I have made __init__.py file as well

Tags: python, importerror

I am having this error while I run the project:

from .miner import Miner
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

[1--> init file, 2--> malicious miner.py which shoes the above-mentioned error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvIIO.png)

As it is mentioned in the picture I have a module name miner, there is also init to make share the proper module import, I have double-checked the files but somehow this error is presenting. Can Someone please help me to solve this issue?

This is the init file:

from .miner import Miner
from .malicious_miner import MaliciousMiner

while importing it doesn't show any error but when I run the file

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to use PyCharm. Creating and importing files from the IDE really helps a lot in this type of problems, because it's not only creating an `init`. I would like to help you further if using PyCharm won't solve the problem

Comment: Yes I am using PyCharm but error is still there

Comment: just got a doubt. why is it .miner and not miner?

Comment: because it is a module, the hierarchy is ((network simulation) --> (miner )--> init --> malicious miner --> and miner ) I have tried (from miner.miner) as well

Comment: to avoid the circular import, I have changed the name of the miner package to miners but the import error is still there